# Java: correct way to escape string for OS-dependent call via Runtime.getRuntime().exec()

Tags: java, operating-system, escaping

In my Java app, I need to call another runnable jar. It looks like this:

```
String path_to_jar_file = "/path/to/app.jar";
String some_params      = "-par1 -par2 -par3";

//-- perform system call
Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar " + path_to_jar_file + " " + some_params);

//-- echo output
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(
      new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream())
      );
String line = null;
while ((line = input.readLine()) != null){
   System.out.println(line);
}

//-- wait until process is finished and get its exit code
int exitVal = pr.waitFor();
```

But `path_to_jar_file` is actually provided by user, so this path could contain spaces, or whatever.
On Windows, I can just quote it, like this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar \"" + path_to_jar_file + "\" " + some_params);
```

and it works. But on Linux, surprizingly, it doesn't work. (no exception is thrown, nothing is echoed, just exit code is 1, which indicates error)

The strange thing is that if I type this command in the terminal (with quotes), it works! But, if I call it via `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` , it works only without quotes.

The only solution I came up with is to use Apache Common's `SystemUtils.IS_OS_WINDOWS` : on windows, quote the path, and on linux escape spaces and other symbols.

But probably there is some ready-made solution for that?

Comment: First try to run he command by hand on the linux terminal, then copy the string and paste it into the exec (as one string exactly as it was in the terminal) then try again. If both of those work then you know that its an issue with the way you are creating the string/path/params in your program.

Comment: @sorifiend, in my Java program, before calling exec() I actually echo the command: `System.out.println(command);`   then I copy-paste this command in the terminal, and it works there! But it doesn't when I execute it via `exec()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested your code and had the same problem as you on OSX.

Your issue seems to be related to blank spaces, I was able to get around the issue by using a [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) since it works much better with spaces.

```
    //Create and start process builder
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", path_to_jar_file, param1, param2, param3);
    Process process = builder.start();

    //Create reader to get error messages (Just in case you have another issue)
    BufferedReader errinput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        process.getErrorStream()));

    //Print errors to the terminal/console
    String s = null;
    while ((s = errinput.readLine()) != null)
    {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

The above code works on Windows and OSX, Linux should behave the same way as OSX.

Remember to take out the error reporting code when you are done, because it will lock the main thread.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have tested it on linux with path containing spaces and some special characters, it works fine. Haven't tested it on Windows yet (with path containing spaces), hope it will work.